# Adjusting the number indexes for the Stem-Leaf plot in R

Tags: r, plot, statistics, probability, stem

How would I be able to edit the r code below so that I can use the integers as the stems and tenths as the leaves in the stem-leaf plot.

```
data_ <- c (130.38, 129.39, 131.75, 131.32, 129.5, 132.79)
sort_data <- sort(data_)
stem(sort_data)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your desired output but you may  [try function by rawr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39309193/how-to-draw-a-stem-and-leaf-plot-which-shows-the-real-leaf-without-rounding-up).

I slightly change that function to fit your purpose.

```
stem2 <- function(x) {
  cx <- gsub('^.*\\.', ', ', as.character(sort(x)))
  co <- capture.output(stem(x))
  m <- gregexpr('\\d(?!.*\\|)', co, perl = TRUE)
  l <- regmatches(co, m)
  l <- t(do.call('rbind', lapply(l, `length<-`, max(lengths(l)))))
  l[!is.na(l)] <- cx
  regmatches(co, m) <- data.frame(l)
  cat(gsub(' , ', ' ', co), sep = '\n')
}
stem2(data_)

  The decimal point is at the |

  129 | 39, 5
  130 | 38
  131 | 32, 75
  132 | 79
```

Comment: meant the first decimal place for the leaf only but that will do I guess thank you.